# amalgamation of locally finite groups

Tags: group-theory

It is well known that in category of groups there are Push-outs so it is possible to realize amalgamation in some kind of most free way. My question is what about category of locally free groups? I think there are not Push-outs so the question is can we realize every amalgamation? (i.e. for every situation $f:H\to G_1$, $g:H\to G_2$ in locally finite groups there is locally finite group $G$ and $f':G_1\to G$, $g':G_2\to G$ such that $f'f=g'g$)

Comment: As stated, it works with $G$ trivial. Presumably you also require those arrows to be universal? But then asking for amalgams is just asking for pushouts, which you don't think exist...

Comment: well I forget to say that I want $f',g'$ to be monomorphisms and the point is that push out is unique in some categorial point of view but amalgamtion need not be

Comment: Ah, I see. So you just want to embed any two LF groups in another LF group along a common subgroup?

Comment: yes for me that is called amalgamation

Comment: Cross-posted on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203345/amalgamation-of-locally-finite-groups, where a negative answer was provided by Derek Holt.